# t=L in neutrino oscillation

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, neutrinos

What do we actually mean when we make the so called *ultrarelativistic* approximation and set the propagation time $T$ equal to the source-detector distance $L$? One would expect $vT=L$, where $v$ is the speed of neutrino.

Answer (score 3):

The ultrareletivistic approximation is precisely the approximation $v\approx c$ so that in this case $T=L$ where we use units such that $c=1$. Neutrinos are so light that in ordinary reference frames (ones attached to the Earth for example), they essentially always travel at the speed of light.